# Saving files created in Docker container to local machine

Tags: docker, mount, docker-volume, mounted-volumes

I have very little knowledge about Docker and I am facing this issue.

I am creating system, where at the beginning I need two containers running, in first there will be GUI for system and next one will be database. When button in GUI will be pressed, new container will be created where server will be running, this server retrieves pages that will be scraped from DB and create multiple scraper containers and assign each scraper webpages to scrape.

In each scraper, files with content are created and stored in specific folder (for example directory named "data"). How can I get this whole directory from these scraper containers to my local machine when process is finished? I guess it needs to be sent in the way containers were created so from scraper -> server -> GUI and from GUI to my local machine.

Can anyone help me and give me some advise how this can be done?

I was advised to use MOUNT and VOLUME but have no idea how this works.

Thanks for your advises.

Comment: A setup where containers launch other containers is complex and kind of advanced, and I'd try to avoid it.  Architecturally I would try to avoid sharing files between containers if at all possible, maybe preferring to store data in the database.  You don't say what application framework you're using; can you set up long-running scrapers using a message queue like RabbitMQ, or a similar work-queue system?

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your comment. That process of creating container from GUI and then creating scrapers from server is unchangeable. I have GUI created in Flask and then server as python script and also scraper is python script. Also data must be stored in files. Only change that maybe I can do is to store files in some cloud store via some API instead of sotring it locally. This will be done only if these mounting of files won't be done.